# Converting "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" timestamp to "yyyyMMdd"

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

Sample Input:

```
{
  "transactionDateTime": "2023-12-05T16:56:15.912Z"
}
```

DataWeave code:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings

var date = payload.transactionDateTime as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"} as String {format: "yyyyMMdd"}
output application/json  
---
{
    "k": date
}
```

Below is the error:

```
Cannot coerce String (2023-12-05T16:56:15.912Z) to LocalDateTime, caused by: Unknown pattern letter: T

14| var CURRENTDATEOriginalPostDate = payload.transactionDateTime as LocalDateTime {format:"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"} as String {format:"yyyy-MM-dd"}
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at main::main (line: 14, column: 35)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case "Z" is not a literal. The [date-time format character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) "X" (zone-offset 'Z' for zero) could be used.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ 
    k: payload.transactionDateTime as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"} as String {format: "yyyyMMdd"}
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "k": "20231205"
}
```